# how do I get the query string parameters in lightning component salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I am trying to get the url query string parameters from current page and I have the following code:

```
doInit: function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    console.log("params::: ", urlParams);
    if (urlParams.has("openSidebar") && urlParams.get("openSidebar") == true) {
      console.log("redirection happening....");

      component.set("v.showFeed", true);
      component.set("v.isSidebarOpen", true);
    }
  },
```

for some reason seems that I cannot use this line **var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);** and I dont know why.

Are there any alternative or salesforce way hwo to get the query string parameters from url?

I am basically getting nothing, the execution seems to stop at the line where I am using **URLSearchParams**!

Also curious to know why does lightning does not let plain javascript to execute in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `new URLSearchParams` will return an instance of a class, not an object (or map).

You can use this code to convert the key/pair values into an object. Then you can check the value on the object instead:

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams('?openSidebar=true&foo=bar&test=hello%26world')
const params = [...searchParams.entries()].reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[k] = v, a), {})
console.log(params)


if (params.openSidebar === 'true') {
  console.log("redirection happening....");
  // do stuff here      
}
```

> Note, we use `=== 'true'` since the url parameter will always be a type of string.

Since you said it wasn't working, you could build your own parser:

```js
const qs = '?openSidebar=true&foo=bar&test=hello%26world'
  .slice(1) // remove '?'

const d = decodeURIComponent // used to make it shorter, replace d with decodeURIComponent if you want
const params = qs
  .split('&') // split string into key/pair
  .map(s => s.split('=')) // split key/pair to key and pair
  .reduce((a, [k, v]) => ((a[d(k)] = d(v)), a), {}) // set each object prop name to k, and value to v

console.log(params)
```

> Note, we use `decodeURIComponent()` (or shorthand `d()`) *last*, because the parameters may contain ampersands or equals signs. Should we call `d()` first, we would split on these characters, which we don't want to happen.

Comment: the execution is stoping right after using const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(
     "?openSidebar=true&foo=bar&test=hello%20world"
    );

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I have no clue what is wrong, since this code works fine for me, I'll write a parser anyway

Comment: just so you know this code exists under lightning component salesforce framework, do you think this might be an issue too?

Comment: If you can't run my code, I would assume it was something to do with your machine exclusively

Comment: yeah the code works perfectly fine when I try in jsfiddle, so basically its not working under this lightning component function init

Comment: @Mizlul I would guess so. Have a look at my edit and see if that works.

Answer (score -1):

URLSearchParams() wasn't working on my browser as well but I came up with a helper function that gets the job done.

```js
function getURLSearchParameters() {
  const urlSearchParameters = {};
  let searchParameters = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search);
  if (searchParameters !== '') {
    searchParameters = searchParameters.substring(1).split('&'); // get ride of '?'
    for (let i = 0; i < searchParameters.length; i++) {
      [key, value] = searchParameters[i].split('=');
      urlSearchParameters[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return urlSearchParameters;
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't answer your other questions because I don't have any experience with salesforce

Comment: does not seem to work, i think its hanging somewhere between:  [key, value] = searchParameters[i].split('=');
      urlSearchParameters[key] = value;